# interpret the intercept and coefficients of normalized input variables in regression model

Tags: regression-coefficients, normalization

My target variable of regression model is a rate between 0 - 1. When using the original input variables, it is easy to interpret the intercept, say 0.8, and coefficients of each input variable, say 0.005 etc.

But when using the normalized input variables to fit same regression model, the intercept was changed to 1.2, and coefficients of each input variable was also changed.

So in this case, how to interpret the intercept and coefficients of the normalized input variables? If the rescaling is a right way to do?

Answer (score 1):

The intercept is still the predicted value when all the input variables are 0, only now, that is 0 after normalization which would be (usually) the mean of the variables on the original scale.

The coefficients are still the predicted change in the target per unit change in the input, but now, they are per normalized unit (usually) the standard deviation.

As a side note, if your target is bounded, the assumptions of linear regression are likely to be violated. You might want to look at beta regression.

Comment: Thanks so much for the helpful tips. May I know if the rescaling method could convert the intercept and coef? Or it just convert the input variables only? I used the Lasso and Elastic Net Regression model with Python Scikit-Learn under an assumption of linear relationship between target and independent variables.

Comment: It could change everything.